# Retrieve list of user emails for specific node

Tags: fiware

during the process of discontinuing our node we need to retrieve the user emails in order to notify them to migrate their VM's.
We have tried using keystone user-list after sourcing our openrc config file but to no avail. 
Is there a command sequence we should use in order to retrieve what we need?

Answer (score 0):

There is an way to get the information about the users that can be using your node. The steps that you should follow are the following:

1. Get the id of your region from the GET to http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/OS-EP-FILTER/endpoint_groups
2. Get the complete list of projects in your region: GET to [http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/OS-EP-FILTER/endpoint_groups/{{Region-Id}}/projects](http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/OS-EP-FILTER/endpoint_groups/%7B%7BRegion-Id%7D%7D/projects) where Region-id comes from endpoints_groups[i].id in the previous JSON response.
3. Get the user of those project, for each project: GET to [http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/role_assignments?scope.project.id={{project_id}}](http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/role_assignments?scope.project.id=%7B%7Bproject_id%7D%7D), where project_id comes from projects[i].id in the previous JSON response.
4. Get detailed information of the user: GET to [http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/users/{{user-id}](http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v3/users/%7B%7Buser-id%7D) where user-id comes from role_assignments[i].user.id in the previous JSON response.

Keep in mind that all the operations have to be done with the corresponding X-Auth-Token.

I hope that it can help you.

Comment: Please take a look to the script implementation in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-skuld/tree/develop/scripts/userListPerRegion repository